# Book about a woman meeting an alien prince, with whom she has a son who then has to escape aliens trying to kill him

Tags: story-identification, aliens

It starts out with this woman driving who is lonely and wants a "magic man."

She meets an alien prince who is hiding out with his personal bodyguard. They've come to earth in the middle of a war on their home planet. He calls the bodyguard a thorn in his side. The alien prince and the woman fall in love.

The alien prince leaves behind the human woman, who has a son in his absence.

Aliens return to earth to take the son. The prince sends a message to the woman that makes her disappear on the spot. (I think she was taken to be with the alien prince, who didn't know he had a son).

So the son is left behind on Earth to fight off hybrids who are trying to kill him. The novel ends with him escaping on a motorcycle.

I remember a great deal of the story but not what it was called. Does anyone here know? Thanks.

Comment: Do you remember when you read it and in what language, how long it was, when it may have been written? What did the cover look like? I'd like to read this, and I've favourited it. :)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like [Invasion America](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_America), a novel by [Christie Golden](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christie_Golden)

> “The story begins in the early 1980s with Cale, the ruler of Tyrus, looking into his uncle's project with Earth, believing it to be  a plan to establish peaceful  contact with humanity. However, his uncle, The Dragit, claims  that their dying planet ought  to invade Earth, conquer the bellicose humans and take hold of its resources. Cale refuses and a civil war breaks out.
>
> “Cale and his bodyguard/trainer/trusted friend Rafe escape to the Utah desert where Cale is ([as per the book by Golden], confronted by some 'rogue' Manglers,) rescued by Rita Carter (who was before-that-moment driving through the desert, thinking about her personal life) a human woman who guides the Tyrusians through human living and becomes a Love Interest for Cale. After a few years of hiding on Earth, Cale returns to Tyrus to lead the loyalist forces (the Ooshati) that have organized, leaving Rita and their young son, David, under Rafe's protection.
>
> “In the present day, when the Dragit finally finds the family, he is determined to kill them (so that there is no threat of a coup), and David Carter's teenage life is thrown into a devastating adventure of stopping the Dragit, losing and gaining friends, and finding out just who he is."

Comment: The novel Christie Golden wrote was the novelization of a cartoon by the same name.

Comment: Omg, this is it! Thank you! Now I can find it and read it again.

Comment: @seeker: Then, can you put a check-mark on my answer?